# Ingresar formula con un for

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito realizar la siguiente operación.
Ejemplo, tengo un arreglo  `cantidad = [420, 940, 920, 850,970];` y un `ancho = 4500`.

La fórmula funciona así:

```
420 + 940 / 2 = 890;
940 / 2 + 920 / 2 = 930;
920 /2 + 850 /2 = 885;
850 / 2 + 970 /2 = 910;
4500-890-930-885-910 = 885;
4500-890-930-885-910 = 885 -970/2 = 400;
```

¿Cómo lo realizo en JavaScript?

Comment: Debes mejorar la pregunta. Tal y como está ahora, es muy difícil entenderla, y no está muy clara la lógica que sigue la fórmula/operación que realizas. Además, sería mejor si presentases lo que hayas intentado y dónde estés teniendo problemas (junto a los posibles mensajes de error), para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var ancho = 4500;
var matriz = [420, 940, 920, 850, 970];
var num = 0;
var restoAncho = 0;
for(var i=0; i < matriz.length; i++){
    if(i === 0){
        num = matriz[i];
    }else{
        if(i > 1) num = matriz[i-1]/2;
        num = num+(matriz[i]/2);
        restoAncho -= num;
    }
}

var resultado = ancho + restoAncho -(matriz[matriz.length-1]/2) ;
console.log('resultado = '+ resultado);
```

Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 1):

Saludos Eduard,

Podrías empezar por un poco de lectura, ejemplo http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ como hacer un recorrido de un arreglo con JQuery.

Luego de eso, sigue la lógica que acabas de escribir.
Espero te sirva más esto, que escribirte el código.

Suerte!